# Changing CSS via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i change the **"background-image"** on **.btn-1** to the variable **"color"** that i have on the script?
I basically want to change the 3color gradient property of the CSS .btn-1 using JS.

```
 <style>
    .btn {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      transition: 0.5s;
      background-size: 200% auto;
      color: white;
     /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
      border-radius: 10px;
     }

    .btn:hover {
      background-position: right center; 
    }

    .btn-1 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <script>
      var color = {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, color1 0%, color2 51%, color3 100%)}
    </script>
      <a name="button" class="btn btn-1">Button Text</a>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I think he forgot to talk about event on button click ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var color` needs to be a string, select the element you want using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) then apply the gradient with `element.backgroundImage = color`

```js
var color = 'linear - gradient(to right, color1 0 % , color2 51 % , color3 100 % )'

document.querySelector('.btn.btn-1').backgroundImage = color;
```

```css
.btn {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: white;
  /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.btn-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a name="button" class="btn btn-1">Button Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Taki and thank you so much for your  answer!
I get a problem on my console : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at update ((index):48)

Comment: sorry but i can't tell you why if i can't see the whole code causing the issue, make sure you copied the answer correctly.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqEejY
That's all the code, i only changed the .backgroundImage from your answer to .background-Image because this was the name of the css style of btn-1

Comment: yeah `document.querySelector('.btn.btn-1').background-image` is indeed invalid, you have to use camel casing to change `css` in `js` , if you absolutely want `background-image` use `document.querySelector('.btn.btn-1')['background-image'] = color;`

Comment: document.querySelector('.btn.btn-1')['background-image'] = color; Doesn't do the trick :(
I even tried with jQuery...No luck either.
$('.btn.btn-1').css('background-image', color);

I see no errors on the console...So not sure what is going on - or what i'm missing...
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgRxoK?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add a modifier class for `btn` class. Modifier class is a part of BEM methodology and it is a sort of helper class which used to change behavior or appearance of the element. [Read more about BEM](http://getbem.com).

After you added your modifier class just add it to your element when you need it.

This approach is better in terms of code cleanness and maintenance. Let me know if you have any questions.

Quick example:

```css
.btn {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: white;
 /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: right center; 
}

.btn-1 {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6d365 0%, #fda085 51%, #f6d365 100%);
}

.btn-1--extra {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, color1 0%, color2 51%, color3 100%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a name="button" id="button" class="btn btn-1">Button Text</a>
  </div>
  <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.classList.add("btn-1--extra");
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello Bohdan and thank you for your answer!
Uhmm color1,color2 and color 3 are variables themselfs for the coresponding colors, that's why i wanted to have them on the script so i can change them.Them being on the styles i cant dynamicly change them as vars there.